# figure text label not working in line chart plotly python

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to create a line charts with text labels on the chart itself but it is not working. **It is
working perfectly fine in scatter plot with the text parameter which you can see below.**

code -

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(crime2,
                 x='murder',
                 y='burglary',
                 size='population',
                 text='state')  # add figure label
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Murder Rate',
                  yaxis_title='Burglary Rate')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))
fig.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with figure text labels]

But it's not working with line chart.
code for line chart -

```
fig = px.line(covid_subset,
              x='date',
              y='total_cases',
              color='location',
              text='location'
)
fig.update_layout(title='Cumulative Confirmed covid-19 cases')
fig.show()
```

[image: line chart with text label]

As you can see instead of show the country label on the line chart only at one place it kept showing all over the line.

**I might missing some parameter but I don't know what is it.**

**This is what I am trying to do -**

[image: covid line chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually how the parameter `text` is supposed to work: show a text all the time it appears on the given column. I have in mind two possible workarounds one with a trick and the other with [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#multiple-annotations). These are not ideal solutions but you can start from here.

## Get Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

url = "https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/raw/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

countries = ["Brazil", "Germany", "India", "Indonesia", "Italy",
             "Mexico", "New Zealand", "Norway", "South Africa",
             "South Korea", "United States"]

df = df[df["location"].isin(countries)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

## Annotations

```py
grp = df.groupby("location")[["date", "total_cases"]].last().reset_index()

annotations = []
for i, row in grp.iterrows():
    annotations.append(
    dict(x=row["date"],
         y=row["total_cases"],
         text=row["location"],
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        showarrow=True,
#         arrowhead=7,
        ax=50,
        ay=0
        ))
    
    
fig = px.line(df,
              x='date',
              y='total_cases',
              color='location',
)
fig.update_layout(title='Cumulative Confirmed covid-19 cases',
                  title_x=0.5,
                  showlegend=False,
                  annotations=annotations)
fig.show()
```

[image]

## Trick

```py
df["date"] = df["date"].astype("M8")

grp = df.groupby("location")[["date", "total_cases"]]\
        .last().reset_index()
grp["text"] = grp["location"].copy()

grp["date"] = grp["date"] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=5)

df1 = pd.concat([df, grp], ignore_index=True, sort=False)\
        .sort_values(["location", "date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

df1["text"] = np.where(df1["text"].isnull(), "", df1["text"])

fig = px.line(df1,
              x='date',
              y='total_cases',
              color='location',
              text="text",
              hover_data={"text":False}
)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center') 
fig.update_layout(title='Cumulative Confirmed covid-19 cases',
                  title_x=0.5,
                  showlegend=False,)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate that you go above and beyond to pull the data from owid github repo and made the plot to explain it

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly more compact/DRY alternative:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country")
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: fig.add_annotation(
    x=t.x[-1], y=t.y[-1], text=t.name, 
    font_color=t.line.color,
    ax=5, ay=0, xanchor="left", showarrow=False
))
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. But here what will be great to have something like Our World in Data. What I mean is that with many traces it will be hard to distinguish one annotation from the other.

Comment: Yep. Text avoidance is a very challenging problem, and something that would need to be handled in Plotly.js but we will likely need a sponsor for that: not something we can take on on our own at the moment.